# receiver_id not saving - rails messaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm implementing my own user messaging feature in my application, but I'm having difficulty retaining the `receiver_id`.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tickets
    has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id', :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id', :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
end
```

Message controller:

```
def new
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @message = Message.new( 
      :receiver => @user )
end

def create
    @message = current_user.sent_messages.create( params[:message] )
    redirect_to( tickets_path, :message => 'Message has been sent.' )
end
```

`receiver_id` in the db remains null.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

Routes question here - [ticket has users that can send messages - rails messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393768/ticket-has-users-that-can-send-messages-rails-messaging)

Comment: This is really two completely different questions.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask about the routes in a separate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is stateless, so each request knows nothing about the one(s) before it. Thus, setting an attribute when calling `Message.new` in the controller doesn't carry over to the `create` request on its own—you need to have a hidden form field containing it. Assuming you're using `form_for`, it would be something like so:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Do you have a solution that does not use hidden fields?

Comment: You could store it in the session, but that's likely to cause more problems than it solves (e.g. what if the user opens the form twice at the same time?). There's no real good way around it, given the way HTTP works.